# Tinymce not fully disabled in chrome

Tags: tinymce, readonly

I want to make a tinymce box disabled which I sort of manage but in chrome the content still is editable to a limited extent. I will explain below:

I first initialize the editor, then I disabled the editor if another parameter is true. I disable the editor with this command:

```
tinyMCE.get('taClientInformationNotebook').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

This disabled the editor however in chrome, if I mark some text in the editor, and press any key on the keyboard the text gets replaced with the pressed character. However it is only possible to press a key once, any further input will be ignored.

So you could say that in chrome the tinymce box is disabled fully but allows for one character to be input. Very strange..

No problems in IE.
How to disable fully in chrome? I've also tried disabling the editor with other commands like "myeditor.setMode('readonly')" and "editor.settings.readOnly=true" but with the same results.